# Localstorage incrementing array to 20

Tags: jquery

**My Setup**
I have a Home, About, and Contact page. There is nothing on pages but each of the 3 links on each of the 3 pages and a button in the middle of each page.

**My Goal**
The URL from the session the button is clicked in, is pushed into an array that can hold up to 20 links.  It can be the same page multiple times,
but essentially, the button can be clicked 20 times(I'll figure out how to catch if it's done in the same session later).

**My Issue**

I'm having trouble passing both the URL from the current session and the building array that the current URL will be passed into, into that same building array. Here is what I'm currently working with:

```
var seshStore = [],
        localStore = [],
        currentUrl = window.location.href,
        newLink = $('<a class="new-link" href="' + currentUrl + '">new link</a>');


$(document).ready(function(){

        // push into local store from last sesh
        var storedLinks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localStore"));
        var restoredLocalStore = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("restoredLocalStore"));
        localStore.push(storedLinks);
        localStore.push(restoredLocalStore);

        for (var i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
            console.log(localStore[i]);
        }
        localStorage.setItem("restoredLocalStore", JSON.stringify(localStore));



        $('.link-button').click(function(){
            $(newLink).appendTo('body');
            var reInitLink = currentUrl;

            // push current url to sesh for its storage and a temp storage for local until next sesh
            // seshStore.push(reInitLink);
            // localStore.push(reInitLink);

            localStorage.setItem("localStore", JSON.stringify(window.location.href));

            // console.log(seshStore);
        });
        // localStorage.clear();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have no initialization for the localStorage "**localStore**".

Currently you set variable **localStore** as **array**.

Try to set it like:

```
localStorage.localStore = "";
```

**localStorage only supports strings**.

Use **JSON.stringify()** [as you used] and **JSON.parse()** [for getting values].

```
// Setting values
var example = ["link1", "link2", "link3"];
localStorage.setItem("names", JSON.stringify(names));

// Getting values
var localStore = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("localStore"));
```

Kindly modify your code as you wish.

Comment: It returned "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ."

Should I leave it as array and than join before putting in localstorage?

Comment: try to set the initialization of localStorage.localStore = "";  to different page other than the page where start passing values to it. So it will not set to "null" on every page load. OR add if statement that check if the localStorage.getItem("localStore") != "" then don't do the setting to "".